# Interactive benchmarking and series selection in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, frontend

i've been toying with highcharts for the past week for a client project. what an amazingly powerful tool, such a great resource!

the problem at hand is that my simple annual analysis of production expenditures isn't what they were wanting after all and now i need a super quick turnaround on getting the desired product out the door. hence my posting.

what i need to figure out how to do is have users interact with the chart (column) such that they can choose from several producers and select one as for 90, 75, or 50 percentile benchmarking. this benchmark then will be the last of the series (far right) as the others (which had been selected, whether only 1 or the other 4) populate in.

here's what i had in its entirety: http://jsfiddle.net/UBYqY/

and here is the more relevant chunk of code therein:

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: ['#5e9a88', '#FF0000'],
            color: '#6ba896',
            shadow: false,
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            },

            events: {
                legendItemClick: ' ',
                checkboxClick: function (event) {
                    if (event.checked) {
                        this.show();
                    } else {
                        this.hide();
                    }
                }
            },

            showCheckbox: true

        },

    },
    series: [{
        name: "Faruqh",
        data: [360.85, 380.90],
        borderColor: "#dc7539"

    }, {
        name: "Debra",
        data: [551.59, 500.29],
        borderColor: "#dc7539"

    }, {
        name: "Dennis",
        data: [266.24, 282.28],
        borderColor: "#dc7539"

    }]
```

thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this example http://jsfiddle.net/UBYqY/7/ ?

```
 $("select").change(function(){
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["Awesome"]);
    chart.addSeries({
        name: "75%",
        data: [400] 
    });

});
```